checking for an earlier presence of an identifier when declaring syntax
I wouldn't say I'm new to vi/vim, as I've been using it for ages now, but I still have a lot to learn when it comes to more sophisticated features. Right now I'm trying to work on my own syntax file, and I'm wondering if it's possible to check if an identifier I'm using has been declared earlier in the file.
For example, let's assume a very simplified pseudocode:
declare foo
set foo to 123 # foo gets marked as an identifier
set bar to 234 # bar gets marked as an error

is such a thing even possible? whenever declare x is encountered, x is saved to memory, and when a variable is expected, it's checked for previous existence - and then different markup is used depending on the result?
and in case it actually is possible, is it possible to include external files?
for example would it be possible to handle something like the following (extending the previous example):
foo.code
declare foo

bar.code
include foo.code
set foo to 123 # foo gets marked as an identifier
set bar to 234 # bar gets marked as an error

I'm not hoping for much, as after all it's meant to be syntax, not logic... but on the other hand I know vim can do crazy stuff when necessary :)

I don’t think this is possible with syntax, but I’ll let the experts answer. You could write an analysis program that sets textprops or similar. Or just write a :compiler plugin and run :make :)

Sounds as if you were interested in static analysis. There are plugins which will run linters on your code and report their errors.
